# Cannot use python extension in WSL vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

When I start vscode from a WSL terminal no python environment is available. I have Python installed and also the Python extension for vscode.

Here is what my vscode looks like.

[image: My vscode environment in WSL]

Comment: your question will be more suited on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for VSCode to use the Python extension it must be installed on the machine where the code resides. On your case you must install the extension inside WSL, just click on the button saying `install on WSL` and it should work.